# Transmit xml serialized objects thru named pipe (without WCF)

Tags: c#, pipe, xmlserializer, named

i want to send specific objects thru a simple named pipe. I think the receiver does not recognize the cut between two sent objects. In the result, i get an xml serialization error. Here is my code:

Server process:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace NamedPipe
{
class ProgramServer
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NamedPipeServerStream server;
            server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece");

            server.WaitForConnection();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);
            Console.WriteLine("Start loop. ");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            while (true)
            {
                XmlSerializer receiver = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PayLoad));
                object testobj = receiver.Deserialize(reader);
                Console.WriteLine("Testobject: " + ((PayLoad)(testobj)).name + ((PayLoad)(testobj)).count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client process:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace NamedPipe
{
    class ProgramClient
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Client
            var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("PipesOfPiece");
            client.Connect();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);

            while (true)
            {

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);
                PayLoad test = new PayLoad
                ()
                {
                    name = "Test",
                    count = 42
                };

                XmlSerializer sendSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PayLoad));
                sendSerializer.Serialize(writer, test);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried recently using NamedPipes without WCF. You can look into this code which might give you some idea. Here, Client is enabled with Callback functionality so server can callback the client.

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName33";
            const string OBJECT_NAME = "test";
            const string CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName34";
            const string CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME = "testclient";

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if ((args.Length == 0 || args[0] == "s"))
            {
                try
                {
                   IPCRegistration.RegisterServer(PIPE_NAME,OBJECT_NAME);
                }
                catch (RemotingException)
                {
                                        remoteObject = IPCRegistration.RegisterClient(typeof(RemoteObject),PIPE_NAME,OBJECT_NAME);
                    remoteObject.OnNewProcessStarted("test");
                    Application.Exit();
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Server:" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "c");
                Application.Run(new Form1("Server"));

            }
            else
            {
                IsClient = true;
                remoteObject = IPCRegistration.RegisterClient(typeof(RemoteObject), PIPE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
                IPCRegistration.RegisterServer(CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME, CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME); // Here Client will listen on this channel.
                remoteObject.SetOnNewProcessStarted(OnNewProcessStarted,Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Client:" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                Application.Run(new Form1("Client"));

            }
        }


        static RemoteObject remoteObject;

        static bool IsClient = false;
        static bool OnNewProcessStarted(string commandLine)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("saved:"+commandLine+" Currrent:"+Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            MessageBox.Show("Is Client : " + IsClient);//problem here, IsClient should be true
            return true;
        }
    }

    public delegate bool OnNewProcessStartedDelegate(string text);

    internal class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public OnNewProcessStartedDelegate OnNewProcessStartedHandler;
        public string value;
        public bool isCallBack = false;
        const string PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName33";
        const string OBJECT_NAME = "test";
        const string CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME = "testPipeName34";
        const string CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME = "testclient";
        RemoteObject remoteObject;
        public bool OnNewProcessStarted(string commandLine)
        {
            if (!isCallBack)
            {
                remoteObject.isCallBack = true;
                return remoteObject.OnNewProcessStarted(commandLine);
            }

            if (OnNewProcessStartedHandler != null)
                return OnNewProcessStartedHandler(value);
            return false;
        }



        public void SetOnNewProcessStarted(OnNewProcessStartedDelegate onNewProcessStarted,string value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnNewProcessStartedHandler = onNewProcessStarted;
            if (!isCallBack)
            {
                remoteObject = IPCRegistration.RegisterClient(typeof(RemoteObject), CALLBACK_PIPE_NAME, CALLBACK_OBJECT_NAME);
                remoteObject.isCallBack = true;
                remoteObject.SetOnNewProcessStarted(onNewProcessStarted, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString());
            }
        }

        public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    internal class IPCRegistration
    {
       public  static RemoteObject RegisterClient(Type remoteObject,string PIPE_NAME,string OBJECT_NAME)
        {
            IpcClientChannel chan = new IpcClientChannel();
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);

            RemoteObject remoteObjectInstance = (RemoteObject)Activator.GetObject(remoteObject,
                    string.Format("ipc://{0}/{1}", PIPE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME));
            return remoteObjectInstance;
        }
        public static void RegisterServer(string pipeName, string objectName)
        {
            BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
            serverProvider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;

            IpcServerChannel chan = new IpcServerChannel("", pipeName, serverProvider);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);

            RemotingServices.Marshal(new RemoteObject(), objectName);
        }
    }
```